# SELECT * FROM with JPA for many-to-many relationship

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, jpa, jpql

I want to do a query(SELECT) with inner join using JPQL.
I'm using *hibernate ddl auto* to create tables from the entities.

I have 2 entities, they're relacionated among them by many-to-many relationship(*One studio can be managed by many managers(user) and one manager(user) can manage many studios*).

As you know,  for many-to-many relationship, we use an intermediate table to do a "SELECT" with native SQL, but i'm using JPA and JPQL as query lenguage, so my question is: **How to do JOIN SELECT between 2 tables relacionated among them by many-to-many relationship?**

The entities below are my entities:

**Entity 1(Studio):**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "studio")
public class Studio implements Serializable {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private Integer id;

@Column(name = "studio_name", nullable = false)
private String studioName;

/**
 * Indicates if the studio is active or inactive in the data base.
 */
@Column(name = "active")
private Boolean active;

/**
 * The studio owner is the main manager for a studio.
 */
@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@JoinColumn(name = "studio_owner", referencedColumnName = "id", nullable = false)
private User studioOwner;

/**
 * Represents all the possible managers for this studio.
 */
@ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
private List<User> studioManagers;

//--Getters and setter below
}
```

**Entity 2(User):**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "userr")
public class User implements Serializable  {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private int id;

@Column(name = "user_name", nullable = false, unique = true)
private String userName;

@Column(name = "email", nullable = false, unique = true)
private String email;

@Column(name = "password", length = 60)
private String password;

@Column(name = "name")
private String name;

@Column(name = "last_name")
private String lastName;

@Column(name = "user_state", nullable = false)
@Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
private UserState userState; 

/**
 * The roles for this user.
 */
@ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
private List<Role> roles;

public User() {
}

//--Getters and setter below
}
```

I'm sorry by me English, Im Spanish speaker.

Comment: which record you want? means not getting what you want as o/p?

Comment: Your JPQL is based on CLASSES/FIELDS. You don't think about TABLES. Just do a JOIN on the RELATION FIELD

Answer (score 0):

In StudioRepository.java just write one method

```
List<Studio> findById(Integer id);
```

this will fetch studio with all the users associated with this studio.

eg:
Studio{
  "id": 1,
  "studioName": "some",
  "studioOwner": [
    {
      .....
      ....
    },
    {
      ....
    }
  ]
}

Comment: Does the OP say they are using "Spring Data JPA" ?